# Write Dataset to XML filtering on a column value

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I don't see such overload in the DataSet method WriteXml(). But, in case I am missing something, can you write a DataSet to an XML file filtering on a value of a column?
For example, if the DataSet has column ColumnA, can you write to XML only rows that have ColumnA="123"?

Comment: do you really need to write a complete dataset or only a single datatable?

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn  I need to write a complete dataset (the dataset actually has just one table). Since I posted the question I found a code on-line that allows copying rows from the dataset to another (clone) dataset. This resolved my issue since I then can write to XML from the close dataset.